# Use a regular expression to validate string

Tags: regex, string, doctrine

I want to use regular expression to validate in input value which is a string that could contain upper and lower case, could have blank spaces and it's length could be between 0 and 255 character (0 :user could not give a value the field is nullable)

I have using the following expression but it didn't work

```
/**
     * @var string
     *
     *  @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/[a-zA-Z]{0,255}/",
     *     match=true,
     *     message="NameProj Invalid")
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="NameProj ", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $NameProj ;
```

Comment: Try `"/^[a-zA-Z\s]{0,255}$/"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/^[a-z\s]{0,255}$/i
```

`^` asserts position at start of the string

Match a single character present in the list below `[a-z\s]{0,255}`

**`{0,255} Quantifier`** — Matches between 0 and 255 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

**`a-z`** a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case **insensitive**)

**`\s`** matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

**`$`** asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)
**Global pattern flags**
**`i`** modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of **[a-zA-Z]**)